# Bootstrap modal goes "behind" the backdrop and users can't clic?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and the modal plugin. I'm having an issue with the modal going behind the body "backdrop". It's not the first time I've used this plugin; I never had any problem before.

[image]

[Here is the page showing the problem](http://adp.iosystems.it/en/appartamenti/lista-appartamenti/58357-da-rite-paluzza-il-ronc) (click inquire about in the lower-right of the page).

It think it's a `z-index` issue. Page structure:

```
   <body>
       <!-- Canvas wrapping entirely the content (z-index: 2) -->
       <div class="canvas canvas-property-show">
           <!-- The modal (z-index: 1050) -->
           <div id="modal-iframe-inquiry"></div>
       </div>

       <!-- Navmenu shown only on small viewport (z-index: 1) -->
       <div class="navmenu navmenu-adp navmenu-fixed-left"></div>
   </body>
```

Modal `#modal-iframe-inquiry` has a default `z-index` of 1050.

If I remove the `.navmenu` from the DOM and remove the `z-index` property from `.canvas` **solves the problem**.

Comment: What's the jQuery code to show?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin your right, removing the tag. It's a jquery plugin, made by bootstrap.

Comment: Why do you need a z-index at all on canvas?  What's happening is the modal is rendered within the canvas with `z-index:2` and even though it has a z-index itself of 1050, the background which is outside of the `canvas` element has 1040 which is of course higher than 2 and thus shows over 2.  Just remove `z-index:2` from your canvas css

Comment: But are you doing the `$('#myModal').modal('show');` with the modal hidden before or are you doing something special? It seems to be an issue with the jQuery not the HTML. It's impossible to fix code without seeing it.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, thanks for your help. I'm using the z-index (as suggested [here](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/) because the navmenu.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin there is not `.modal` javascript call, it's triggered by Bootstrap data-attributes.

Comment: @gremo apologies, I saw the Javascript tag and thought it was with Javascript. Should've asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - to fix instead of rendering the `modal-iframe-enquiry` html in the `canvas`
render it before the canvas or after it. e.g.

```
.......             
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal-iframe-inquiry" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-iframe-inquiry-title" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-iframe-inquiry-title">Inquire about</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="embed-responsive" style="height: 640px;">
                                <iframe src="https://app.kigo.net/public/inquiry_embed/2-a77d11161e667005ce29f22b3e7a8d04-1738-f1db7ab2c4c99c15b210e92bd0f90239"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="canvas canvas-property-show">
    ......
```